# Many partial javascript sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timing, pageload

Does many javascript sections on different places affect page loading time?
like

```
<html><script></script><body><script></script></body><script></script></html>
```

Also is there any affects while using referces or writing small script parts on html?
And last, is it bad or good to write many codes on document load in page, will it affect page laod time while compiling all scripts on load

Comment: I think every letter you add will affect load time, it will however be unnoticable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously loading many different external JavaScript files will increase final load time.

You can place all the `<script>` tags at the end of your document, right before the `</body>` so that the website loads before the scripts. If possible you could minify and combine your JS files, to decrease the number of HTTP requests as well.

Page rendering will start as soon as all CSS is loaded and the DOM has been parsed, so this will make it seem like it loads faster.

Try following some recommendations, like the [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), if you are concerned about page speed.

Having JavaScript snippets inline with your HTML would not be a good idea. Try to keep your HTML clean, and use JavaScript with the appropriate selectors if you want to alter the DOM adding or removing any element.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice requires you to load or run javascript at the bottom of the page(footer).
This way all the assets of the page (html, css, images) are loaded first.
Then load and execute javascript code. 
Regarding speed the best way is to put all your js code to one .js file (if possible) and minimize it.
This way you can cut loading time and http requests giving a speed boost to your site.